To what degree can Morph copy the powers and abilities of other Marvel characters?
In X-Men '97, we've seen Morph morph into various iconic Marvel characters like Colossus, Quicksilver, Juggernaut, Hulk, and Mr. Fantastic, and it's clear he can mimic their powers to some degree. But I can't help but wonder about the specifics—just how far can he take these power imitations?
From what we've witnessed so far, Morph's abilities seem to be pretty impressive. In episode 2, his Colossus form appeared to be just as durable as the real deal in shrugging off attacks. Then in episode 7, when he morphed into Quicksilver, he seemed to be moving at the same lightning-fast speed as the speedster himself. And in the episodes where he transformed into the unstoppable Juggernaut (episode 8) and the incredible Hulk (episode 9), he seemed to possess their immense strength. In episode 10, Morph took on the form of Mr. Fantastic and exhibited the same stretching abilities as the Fantastic Four leader. It's almost like he's a one-man Marvel superhero team.
To what extent can Morph copy powers? Depending on the answer, he might very well be one of the most powerful characters (physically) in the Marvel universe. While the TV series hasn't delved too deep into the specifics, I'd love to hear insights from those familiar with Morph's comics iteration. 

And then he decides to morph into the Beyonder and become omnipotent. The end.

Well, according to his profile in Marvel's page, he can stretch any part of his body (like Mr. Fantastic) and he can grow muscles and be able to lift 20 tons but he's no Hulk. He's not really "copying" powers.

Morph is an omnimorph composed of unstable molecules, allowing him to rearrange his body’s molecules at will within a fraction of a second into a highly malleable state. In such a state, he can stretch, deform, expand or compress his entire body or parts thereof into any contiguous shape, object or person he can imagine. He can extend his limbs, torso or neck to great distances and can extend his body in two directions, creating a canopy, parachute or sheath. He retains full consciousness in whatever form taken, and if a part of his body is
severed he can reassemble the parts, but needs time to recover afterward. His “costume” is actually part of his body and he does not give off a scent. He can change color and duplicate the appearance of others, including modifying his vocal chords and using his natural mimicry skills to imitate their voices. By growing additional muscles, he can temporarily enhance his strength to lift approximately 20 tons.
Morph can psionically fly at speeds of 40 mph and give himself virtually any superhuman physical power.

You can also compare Morph's skills against the ones from Hulk or Quicksilver that appear in the same site.
Morph

Hulk

Quicksilver

So, he's strong and he's fast but not the strongest nor the fastest. And he can simulate physical powers (fly, strength, speed...) but he has limits.
Note: Morph's skills above corresponds to the variant from Earth-1081, the one from Exiles and the most powerful of the variants. The original one from Earth-616, created back in 1967, is not even known as Morph and he's even less powerful

